# react native expo prebuild error `UMCore` depended upon by `EXFont`

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I am working on a React Native Project based on a bare workflow, and my project is not working on Xcode.
I use expo modules but when i want to setup my ios project by the command "expo prebuild" i get the following error:

*⚠️  Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod repo update` failed.
└─ Cause: Couldn't install: EXFont » UMCore. Ensure the CocoaPod "UMCore" is installed in your project, then run `npx pod-install` to try again.*

It seems Cocoapods did not install this file.. but i have no idea how to do it.

And When i launch the command "pod install" i get :
"*[!] Unable to find a specification for `UMCore` depended upon by `EXFont`*"

I followed this guide from Expo : https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-migration.md
It works fine on my Android Project.

I got the latest version of Expo and CocoaPods and my Xcode version is 13.0.

Any idea ? I did not found a lot of topics on this subject, and none solve this error...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar errors after updating the expo.
In my case it was:

- *[!] Unable to find a specification for `UMCore` depended upon by `EXSecureStore`*
- *[!] Unable to find a specification for `UMCore` depended upon by `EXLinearGradient`*

**Solution**

```
expo install expo-secure-store
expo install expo-linear-gradient
cd ios
pod install --repo-update --clean-install
```

To solve your issue, I think you need to do:

```
expo install expo-font
cd ios
pod install # or `pod install --repo-update --clean-install`
```